# Advertisement in Notification Bar

Tags: android, notifications, admob, ads

i want to ask if any of you could give me example of code which shows ads of admob.com in notification bar? I know that users probably will hate my app, but i want to give a try. Thank you.

Comment: remove "probably" and prepare for 1 star votes... don't just don't (only valid as a proof of concept)

Comment: Users?  I don't think so.  Anything that puts an ad in my notification bar gets uninstalled right away.  You might get good numbers for installs but active installs?  Hmmm.

Comment: ok, you made me change my mind. thank you :)

Comment: I don't see the problem. Instead of blocking the gameview you have it in the notification bar, i think it's a great solution.

Comment: @Daniel and a unpractical one? Who would pause the game to lower the bar and check if the ad is interesting? Right, nobody! So you can simply skip it...

Answer (score 5):

A while back, Google Play changed it's [Developer Content Policy](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html) (Read section **Ad Policy**) which specifically says:

> Ads must not simulate or impersonate system notifications or warnings.

So if you have to implement such a feature, you risk getting a warning or removal from Google Play.

Source: [Email sent to Developers after the changes were made to the policy linked above](http://www.androidcentral.com/google-play-developer-policies-have-been-updated-we-where-heading)

That being said, I am now aware of any such restrictions by other platforms such as Amazon primarily because I don't distribute on it yet and never needed to read up on their policies. So, if you need to have such a feature, you will have to use the [AirPush SDK](http://www.airpush.com/android-developers)

Naturally, since Google laid out the policy, AdMod does not the facility of displaying Notification Ads.

So, if the rewards are worth the risk.... ;-)

Comment: Don't use airpush - They are a scam - they never pay (to me and to 2 of my friends) or pay much less due to all sorts of reasons they make up.. (google it)